# My own Custom SeekBar Android

Tags: android, seekbar

I want to create my own SeekBar because I can't find anything like with I need.
I want a seekbar with 3 bands, like this:

(I can't post image, so... )

```
 _____________________________________________________
(    BLUE         |     RED     X       |    BLUE     )
 ˜˜˜˜˜˜˜˜˜˜˜˜˜˜˜˜˜˜˜˜˜˜˜˜˜˜˜˜˜˜˜˜˜˜˜˜˜˜˜˜˜˜˜˜˜˜˜˜˜˜˜˜˜
```

X = thumb

I don't want progress bar, just thumb and 3 background colors..
get the idea?

anyone know how i can do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a really great example that should help you get moving

http://www.mokasocial.com/2011/02/create-a-custom-styled-ui-slider-seekbar-in-android/

However this doesn't address your problem with the tricolor band in the background, as this example uses a repeatable drawable. For that problem I would look at this post
[How to make a color gradient in a SeekBar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4342757/how-to-make-a-color-gradient-in-a-seekbar)
You going to need to create your own gradient. That should give the results you are looking for.

Comment: thanks for your answer but i had looked at this 2 sites and you are right.. don't resolve my problem, but i trying to do with gradients.. maybe i can do something like i want with this..

Comment: i solved my problem with gradients, how suggest our friend, thanks Frank

Answer (score 0):

**XML code**

```
 <SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seek_bar"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:paddingRight="15dp"
    android:thumb="@drawable/thumbler_small"
    android:indeterminate="false" />
```

**seek_bar.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:id="@+android:id/SecondaryProgress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/first"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+android:id/progress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/second"/>
</layer-list>
```

**first drawable is empty or shown not color full area.**

**second drawable is fill or color full area.**

[this](http://custom-android-dn.blogspot.in/2012/12/how-to-use-and-custom-seekbar-in-android.html) link help your more.

Answer (score 0):

May this example could help:

[Android SeekBar and Custom SeekBar Examples](https://www.zoftino.com/android-seekbar-and-custom-seekbar-examples)

Search for 'Seekbar custom thumb output.'

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.