# Simple color picker

Tags: android, colors, color-picker, colordialog

I'm trying to show a simple color picker so that the user can select the color of a few texts... But every color picker I've found so far seems too complicated for my means. I wouldn't mind coding it myself if at least I had some idea of how.

Could anyone provide me with code for some simple color picker?
Or point me in a direction for further research into how to code it?

I'm trying to achieve something like this:
[image]

Comment: Already answered - see post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4342757/how-to-make-a-color-gradient-in-a-seekbar)

Comment: that would be awesome but it doesn't compile, the constructor method for LinearGradient fails

Comment: Checkout this one [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6980906/android-color-picker)

Comment: @Mantas that's actually the code I'm working on right now, I'm kinda teaching myself programming to android so it gets harder when theres no google documentation but I understood most of the code by now I should be able to code my own color picker pretty soon.

Comment: @ArtemioRamirez It compiles now - I posted answer below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

In xml use:

```
<SeekBar
   android:id="@+id/seekbar_font"
   android:layout_width="300dip"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_margin="10px"
   android:max="100"
   android:progress="50"></SeekBar>
```

In activity:

```
LinearGradient test = new LinearGradient(0.f, 0.f, 300.f, 0.0f,
              new int[] { 0xFF000000, 0xFF0000FF, 0xFF00FF00, 0xFF00FFFF,
              0xFFFF0000, 0xFFFF00FF, 0xFFFFFF00, 0xFFFFFFFF}, 
              null, TileMode.CLAMP);
        ShapeDrawable shape = new ShapeDrawable(new RectShape());
        shape.getPaint().setShader(test);

        SeekBar seekBarFont = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekbar_font);
        seekBarFont.setProgressDrawable( (Drawable)shape );
```

Comment: Thx, this almost works except for the fact that the colors only apply for half of the bar I assume it must have something to do with the LinearGradient constructor so I'll look for the documentation and try to fix it.

Comment: @ArtemioRamirez you have to size the bar to match the gradient width or vice versa - notice the 300 in both places - seekbar and gradient

Answer (score 9):

In case of someone else running into this here is the code for retrieving the value:

```
seekBarFont.setMax(256*7-1);
seekBarFont.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            if(fromUser){
                int r = 0;
                int g = 0;
                int b = 0;

                if(progress < 256){
                    b = progress;
                } else if(progress < 256*2) {
                    g = progress%256;
                    b = 256 - progress%256;
                } else if(progress < 256*3) {
                    g = 255;
                    b = progress%256;
                } else if(progress < 256*4) {
                    r = progress%256;
                    g = 256 - progress%256;
                    b = 256 - progress%256;
                } else if(progress < 256*5) {
                    r = 255;
                    g = 0;
                    b = progress%256;
                } else if(progress < 256*6) {
                    r = 255;
                    g = progress%256;
                    b = 256 - progress%256;
                } else if(progress < 256*7) {
                    r = 255;
                    g = 255;
                    b = progress%256;
                }

                seekBarFont.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(255, r, g, b));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });
```