# Gradient Seekbar

Tags: android, seekbar

I'm trying to impement SeekBar with gradient progress:-

[image: like this]

How can I achieve this result?
By now I'm doing it like this (colors are dummy):

```
val colors = intArrayOf(0xFF000000.toInt(), 0xFFFFFF00.toInt())
val progressDrawable = GradientDrawable(GradientDrawable.Orientation.LEFT_RIGHT,
                    colors)
itemView.group_brightness_seekbar.progressDrawable = progressDrawable
```

But it looks pretty ugly and I can't set height of the progress (setSize method affects thumb too)
Thanks in advance for your advice

Comment: Check this:- https://stackoverflow.com/a/4342793/3974530